# Apply styles to text in a string Android

Tags: java, android, string, styles, contains

I'm trying to create a String with SpannableString to apply colors and bold text.

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Salida de la Capilla de María Auxiliadora\n00:00\nMarquesa de Sales\n00:00\nEspíritu Santo\n00:00\nSagasta\n00:00\nPza. Meneses\n00:00\nPozo Nuevo\n00:00\nPza. Ayuntamiento\n00:00\nSan Miguel\n00:00\nEstación de Penitencia, Iglesia San Miguel\n00:00\nÁnimas\n00:00\nMariano Hernández\n00:00\nEduardo Dato\n00:00\nRojas Marcos\n00:00\nPza. Meneses\n00:00\nCarrera\n00:00\nCalzadilla\n00:00\nGregorio María Ferro\n00:00\nMaría Auxiliadora\n00:00\nMarquesa de Sales\n00:00\nEntrada al Templo\n00:00\n");

tv.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

To speed up my work I am trying to create a condition like this:

```
if(WordtoSpan.toString().contains(":")){
// found the text string ":" (00:00)

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(140, 117, 189)), 42, 47, 
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
WordtoSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 42,47, 47);
}else{
//Not found ":"
}
```

I would implement the bold text and color to all the String 00:00. Anyone know any quick and easy way? Do not go telling words to words to fill all the 00:00?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the index of "00:00" , and set it as start index of span , and end index as length of "00:00"

```
    Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Salida de la Capilla de María Auxiliadora\n00:00\nMarquesa de Sales\n00:00\nEspíritu Santo\n00:00\nSagasta\n00:00\nPza. Meneses\n00:00\nPozo Nuevo\n00:00\nPza. Ayuntamiento\n00:00\nSan Miguel\n00:00\nEstación de Penitencia, Iglesia San Miguel\n00:00\nÁnimas\n00:00\nMariano Hernández\n00:00\nEduardo Dato\n00:00\nRojas Marcos\n00:00\nPza. Meneses\n00:00\nCarrera\n00:00\nCalzadilla\n00:00\nGregorio María Ferro\n00:00\nMaría Auxiliadora\n00:00\nMarquesa de Sales\n00:00\nEntrada al Templo\n00:00\n");

    String search = new String("00:00");
    int length = search.length();
    String input = WordtoSpan.toString();
    int startIndex = input.indexOf(search);
    while(startIndex > length)
    {
        WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(140, 117, 189)), startIndex, startIndex + length,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        WordtoSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startIndex, startIndex + length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        startIndex = input.indexOf(search, startIndex + length);
    }
```

You have to loop throughout the string for the index

Comment: Thanks for answering. He shows me the Logcat errors -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29764789/logcat.png

Comment: I copied your code and shows error: The method setSpan (ForegroundColorSpan, int, int, int) is undefined for the type String

Comment: some minor correction. see the updated answer. this should work . I tested now :)

Comment: What do you recommend I change to get on the same string 00:00, 1:00 and 2:00?